# RestSharp Timeout exceeded - best implementation

Tags: .net, vb.net, restsharp

I've some stable implementation on RestSharp querying an HTTP WebAPI WebService with a 60 seconds timeout. Actually this implementation is used on a Windows Service so this WS is receiving lot of requests per day.

The matter is that sometimes I get an error (15 per day aprox.) and no idea how to handle this errors so all request can have an answer. (Actually I'm thinking on retry execution).

```
 Public Sub UpdateQuery(ByVal query As Request)
        Dim client As New RestClient(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SERVICE_URL") & query.Query)
        Dim request = New RestRequest(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SERVICE_URL") & query.Query, Method.PATCH)
        Dim response As New RestResponse
        request.Timeout = 1000 * ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("RequestTimeOut")
        request.AddParameter("application/json", query.Body, ParameterType.RequestBody)
        response = client.Execute(request)

        If response.ErrorException Is Nothing Then
            If response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NoContent Then
                query.StatusCode = response.StatusCode
            Else
                query.StatusCode = response.StatusCode
                query.ErrorDescr = JObject.Parse(response.Content).SelectToken("error.message.value")
            End If
        Else
            response = client.Execute(request)                 'Retry¿?¿?
            If response.ErrorException Is Nothing Then
                query.StatusCode = response.StatusCode
                If response.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.NoContent Then
                    query.ErrorDescr = JObject.Parse(response.Content).SelectToken("error.message.value")
                End If
            Else
                Throw New Exception("UpdateQuery error:, response.ErrorException)
            End If    
        End If    
    End Sub
```

Exception received is this one (translated on Google) -

```
System.Net.WebException : the waiting time of the operation was exceeded
   in System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse ( )
   in RestSharp.Http.GetRawResponse ( HttpWebRequest request)
   in RestSharp.Http.GetResponse ( HttpWebRequest request)
```

Any idea would be helpful. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Maxlength is clearly missing.